# Javascript code not running on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari

I have created a simple image slider using Javascript and JQuery, the code is running fine in safari both locally and online however in Chrome it is not running. Chrome is also throwing up no errors in the console so I'm finding it difficult to pinpoint the exact issue. I realise having read into the problem that I should perhaps have my scripts the other way round so the slider.js goes first then the Ajax one however when I do this the script and therefore images do not load in Safari or Chrome.
Cheers.

I have the following HTML code:

```
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="slider"></div>
  <script src="slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

And JS

```
slideShow();
var imgArray = [
    'Images/image1.jpg',
    'Images/image2.jpg',
    'Images/image3.jpg',
    'Images/image4.jpg',
    'Images/image5.jpg',
    'Images/image6.jpg',
    'Images/image7.jpg',
    'Images/image8.jpg'
  ],
curIndex = 0;
imgDuration = 5000;

function slideShow() {
$("#slider")
  .fadeOut('slow', function() {
      var img = $("<img />")
          .attr('src', imgArray[curIndex])
          .on('load', function() {
              $("#slider")
                  .html(img)
                  .fadeIn('normal', function() {
                      curIndex++;
                      if (curIndex == imgArray.length) {
                          curIndex = 0;
                      }
                      setTimeout(slideShow, imgDuration);
                  });
          });
  });
}
```

Comment: are you loading the page using a server or just the os filesystem?

Comment: I've tried both loading the file locally by using open with Chrome, but also uploading it online to my webpage where it also does not load

Comment: your code, in essence, works for me in any browser - the only thing I had to do (on jsfiddle to test) is to wrap the whole js in `$(function() { ..your code here.. });` - but that was to get it to work with any browser at jsfiddle - try that, see if it helps

Comment: I tried same and works for me - https://jsfiddle.net/r1a3q8f0/

Comment: Jaramonda I have tried that and it is still not working, I wondered if it was my device so have tried to load it on my phone and still no joy, bizarre as Pravin's solution does indeed work for me on jsfiddle on both safari and chrome

Answer (score 0):

You probably have not cleared the timeout timer I think.